# Dynamic header creation based on the row value Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Hi All,

How can I create a dynamic header title, based on the value of the row.

Please check the below table structure:

```
    <table >
    <tr>
    <thead>
    <td>Q1header</td>
    <td>Q2header</td>
    <td>Q3header</td>
    </thead>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>something</td>
    <td>something</td>
    <td>something</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Q1</td>
    <td>Q2</td>
    <td>Q3</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

What I need to do is, I need to create a dynamic header based on the row value.

Example: if it is `Q1`, I need to make header name as `Q1header` like that. If the row value is empty, I don't want to show any header for that column.

Comment: your question is not clear, please be descriptive.

Comment: Based on the row value I need to create header title , sample table structure is mentioned on the question

Comment: Can I implement it in Jquery ?

Comment: what is triggering the dynamic behavior??

Comment: The td value is triggerring that , here in this sample database values are coming as Q1 and Q2 etc . if its Q1 Then I need change the header as Q1header

Comment: And if there is no value on that  TD then I don't want to show the  column header for that

Answer (score 0):

You question is completely unclear and you need to explain in details and clear, so I'm not sure if this is what you want :

```js
// I'm sure it's wrong
;$(function(){
  var $header = $("<h1>Header</h1>");
  var $headers = $("thead td");
  $header.appendTo('body');
  $(document).on("click", "td", function(e) {
    // console.log($(this).index());
    if( $(this).text() == "" ) return;
    $header.text( $headers[$(this).index()].innerText );
    $([$("table td.selected"),$(this)]).toggleClass("selected");
  });
});
```

```css
.selected { color:red;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table >
    <tr>
    <thead>
    <td>Q1header</td>
    <td>Q2header</td>
    <td>Q3header</td>
    </thead>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>something</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>something</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Q1</td>
    <td>Q2</td>
    <td>Q3</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```